# Sphinx-autodoc with napoleon (Google Doc String Style): Warnings and Errors about Block quotes and indention

Tags: python-sphinx, docstring, sphinx-napoleon

I am using Sphinx 4.4.0 with napoleon extension (Google Doc String). I have this two problems

- `ARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.`
- `ERROR: Unexpected indentation.`

I found something about it on the internet but can not fit this two my code. My problem is I even do not understand the messages. I do not see where the problem could be.

This is the code:

```
def read_and_validate_csv(basename, specs_and_rules):
    """Read a CSV file with respect to specifications about format and
    rules about valid values.

    Hints: Do not use objects of type type (e.g. str instead of "str") when
    specificing the column type.

        specs_and_rules = {
            'TEMPLATES': {
                 'T1l': ('Int16', [-9, ' '])
                 },
             'ColumnA': 'str',
             'ColumnB': ('str', 'no answer'),
             'ColumnC': None,
             'ColumnD': (
                 'Int16',
                 -9, {
                     'len': [1, 2, (4-8)],
                     'val': [0, 1, (3-9)]
                 }
             }

    Returns:
        (pandas.DataFrame): Result.

    """
```

This are the original messages:

```
.../bandas.py:docstring of buhtzology.bandas.read_and_validate_csv:11: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
.../bandas.py:docstring of buhtzology.bandas.read_and_validate_csv:15: ERROR: Unexpected indentation.
.../bandas.py:docstring of buhtzology.bandas.read_and_validate_csv:17: ERROR: Unexpected indentation.
.../bandas.py:docstring of buhtzology.bandas.read_and_validate_csv:19: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
.../bandas.py:docstring of buhtzology.bandas.read_and_validate_csv:20: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reStructuredText is not Markdown, and indentation alone is not enough to demarcate the code block. reStructuredText calls this a [literal block](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#literal-blocks). Although the use of `::` is one option, you might want to explicitly specify the language (overriding the default) with the use of the [`code-block` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block).

Also I noticed that you have invalid syntax in your code block—a missing `)` and extra spaces in your indentation—which could have caused those errors.

Try this.

```
def read_and_validate_csv(basename, specs_and_rules):
    """Read a CSV file with respect to specifications about format and
    rules about valid values.

    Hints: Do not use objects of type type (e.g. str instead of "str") when
    specificing the column type.

    ..  code-block:: python

        specs_and_rules = {
            'TEMPLATES': {
                 'T1l': ('Int16', [-9, ' '])
                 },
            'ColumnA': 'str',
            'ColumnB': ('str', 'no answer'),
            'ColumnC': None,
            'ColumnD': (
                'Int16',
                -9, {
                    'len': [1, 2, (4-8)],
                    'val': [0, 1, (3-9)]
                }
            )
        }

    Returns:
        (pandas.DataFrame): Result.

    """
```